# How check fast, if database reachable? (Qt, QML, C++)- Linux

Tags: c++, linux, database, qt, qml

I use qt with qml and c++. On my application i use a database. 
It all works, if the database is reachable.

My problem is, that i would like to check, if database is reachable (like ping).

I tried

```
    db.setDatabaseName(dsn);
    if(db.isValid())
    {

        if(db.open())
        {
            //std::cout <<"Offene Datenbank";
            connected=true;

        }
        else
        {
            connected=false;
        }


    }
    else
    {
        connected=false;
    }
```

and give the connected value as result. But that takes very long (maybe 30 seconds), if there is no connection. How i can check fast, if i have a database connection?

Is there maybe a way to break the command .open after 5 seconds not connected?

Comment: By reachable do you mean the you want to check if the file has been created? or you have correct permissions? or both?

Comment: i would like to know, if i can reach the server like pinging. Because of my profile on the server, i should write/read if i can reach the server-ip.

Comment: the application should return false, if i cant reach the database-server and true if i can reach it or make a connection

Answer (score 1):

I have studied this question a bit. Here is what I found out.

The problem is in default db connection timeout - it is too long. Each db allows you to change it to an acceptable value, using their own API. In Qt there is one common db interface - `QSqlDatabase`. And it does not have such method. You can set connection settings by calling it's `QSqlDatabase::setConnectOptions` method, but it accepts only predefined list of options (which you can read in Qt's help).

For `PostgreSQL` there is an option `connect_timeout`, so you can write:

```
db.setConnectOptions("connect_timeout=5"); // Set to 5 seconds
```

For other databases there is no such parameter. Connection options of each db are parsed in it's 'driver' class, which derives `QSqlDriver` and is stored in a 'driver' library.

So, what you can do:

1. You can rewrite database's driver in order it to accept timeout option.
2. You can write separate code for each db, using it's native API.

**UPDATE**

Turns out, that `ODBC` has `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` option.

**UPDATE 2**

*qsql_odbc.cpp:713*

```
} else if (opt.toUpper() == QLatin1String("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT")) {
    v = val.toUInt();
    r = SQLSetConnectAttr(hDbc, SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, (SQLPOINTER) v, 0);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713605(v=vs.85).aspx

> SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT (ODBC 3.0)
>
> An SQLUINTEGER value
>   corresponding to the number of seconds to wait for any request on the
>   connection to complete before returning to the application. The driver
>   should return SQLSTATE HYT00 (Timeout expired) anytime that it is
>   possible to time out in a situation not associated with query
>   execution or login.
>
> If ValuePtr is equal to 0 (the default), there is no timeout.

Should work fine...

Comment: i have an odbc driver than i should take option 
SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, sure?

Comment: Okey, this is awkward. I've never used ODBC, so I didn't check it's connection options. Yes, I guess you are right - `SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` is exactly what you need.

Comment: hmh i used it in my code but that don't work faster as before

Comment: What value did you set?

Comment: db.setConnectOptions("SQL_ATTR_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=5;SQL_ATTR_LOGIN_TIMEOUT=5");

                if(db.open())
                {
                 
             
                    connected=true;

                }
                else
                {
                    connected=false;
                }

Answer (score 1):

I think one easy solution is to just check the ping of the database sever. You can use platform specific ways for pinging.

This would work on Linux :

```
int exitCode = QProcess::execute("ping", QStringList() << "-c 2" << serverIp);
if (exitCode==0) 
{
    // is reachable
} else 
{
    // is not reachable
}
```

Comment: I think this can be used in conjunction with the other answers given.  If you can't ping the server, you certanly won't be able to establish a connection. That info is returned quickly by ping.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having some separate thread/class where you check connection and emit signal after some timeout if nothing happens (with a check - knowConnection - if we found out already if its connected).
This code is not tested and written from scratch on top of my head.. may contain some errors.

```
/// db connection validator in separate thread
void validator::doValidate() {
 this->knowConnection = false;
 db.setDatabaseName(dsn);
 if(db.isValid())
 {
     QTimer::singleShot(1000, [this]() { 
         if (!this->knowConnection) {
             emit connected(false);dm->connected=false;
         }
     });
     if(db.open())
     {
         //std::cout <<"Offene Datenbank";
         this->knowConnection = true;
         dm->connected=true;
         emit connected(true);
     }
     else
     {
         dm->connected=false;
         this->knowConnection = true;
         emit connected(false);
     }
 } 
 else
 {
     dm->connected=false;
     this->knowConnection = true;
     emit connected(false);
 }
}

/// db manager in different thread
void dm::someDbFunction() {
    if (connected) {
        /// db logic
    }
}

/// in gui or whatever
MainWindow::MainWindow() : whatever, val(new validator(..), .. {      
    connect(val, SIGNAL(connected(bool)), this, SLOT(statusSlot(bool));
    ....
}

void MainWindow::statusSlot(bool connected) {
    ui->statusBar->setText((connected?"Connected":"Disconnected"));
}
```

Comment: the singleshot timer abort after one interval. but i have not the problem in shooting one. the problem is the long delay

Comment: if I understand you.. now the delay would be 1sec and after that if nothing happens in db.open() the singleshot would emit that we have no connection. If you have connection I presumed that db.open() returns right away(and thus sets knowConnection to true etc..)?
Hm.. so the timer works just once.. I will think about that.

Comment: The reason that the default timeout is long is that in some situations connecting to a db can take a long time.  I used to work on a project that had many remote db servers.  Our typical connection time was 7 seconds. Sometimes longer, but rarely, if ever shorter.  It is worth measuring your connection times and adjusting the length of the one shot accordingly, if you go with this implementation.